# limit the number of cores used by MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, setthreadaffinitymask

On Linux, can you ensure that MySQL leaves one core free?

(We have a small Python server that can become unresponsive when MySQL running on the same box is under load.)

Comment: Are you sure this is a CPU thing? It could be IO bound.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/limit-process-to-one-cpu-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways I can think of...

- Use the command ***taskset***.
  This command will "fix" specific core (or list of cores) to a specific process.
  Consult the [***man page***](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html) how to use it
- Create **Virtual machine** on your "little" server and run the mysql on that VM.
  This will promiss more stability to both services
- Use the "***nice***" values to make sure the python priority is higher then the mysql priority.
  (This solution is the least recommanded of all three, but in some cases it can be valid)